# pandas pivot_table to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, dataframe

I have data that looks like this

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = [{'id': 1, 'label': 0, 'code': 'f1'}, {'id': 1, 'label': 0, 'code': 'f2'},
            {'id': 2, 'label': 1, 'code': 'f3'},
            {'id': 2, 'label': 1, 'code': 'f4'}]
df = DataFrame(data)

>>>
    code  id  label
0   f1   1      0
1   f2   1      0
2   f3   2      1
3   f4   2      1
```

I want to reshape the data to be something like this (with proper headers and no incorrect `id-label` associations).

```
   id label  f1  f2  f3  f4
    1     0   1   1   0   0
    2     1   0   0   1   1
```

I tried using `pivot_table`, but with that data looks like this

```
df['val'] = 1
pt_df = df.pivot_table('val', columns='code', index=['id', 'label'], fill_value=0, dropna=False)

>>>
     f1  f2  f3  f4
1 0   1   1   0   0
  1   0   0   0   0
2 0   0   0   0   0
  1   0   0   1   1
```

Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(columns='code', index=['id', 'label'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
code      f1  f2  f3  f4
id label                
1  0       1   1   0   0
2  1       0   0   1   1

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

If you want the id/label info in columns instead of the index, just use `reset_index`.

Your example data set is small, so it's not clear if this will generalize the way you want.  Basically what it does is it sets the value for each combination of id/label and code to the number of rows of the DataFrame having that combination (e.g., the value for id=1, label=0, code=f1 is 1 because there is one row with those values).

Comment: I guess `dropna=False` was causing the incorrect associations to stay. Otherwise this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used unstack, which is essentially pivot...

```
df['vals'] = 1
df = df.set_index(['id' ,'label' ,'code']).unstack('code').fillna(0)
#df = df.reset_index() #to bring out id and label
```